# Xcode 4 workspace: adding framework from project B as dependency to project A

Tags: xcode4, build-process, workspace

This should be simple, but I can't figure out how to do this in Xcode 4:

I have an Xcode workspace with two top level projects:

- Project A (app): the application depends on Framework built by project B
- Project B (framework): one target to build the Framework

I would like to add the Framework target from Project B as a dependency to the application target of Project A. However, in the `Build Phases > Target Dependencies` for Project A's target, I only see Project A (not the framework target of Project B).

I'm still refining the framework so I wold like to have the application target build the framework automatically whenever it changed.

Is there a way to do this without making the framework project a child of Project A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I finally figured out:

With both projects as top level projects in a workspace:

- Add the framework project to Project A, but make sure "Copy.." is not checked when adding it. The framework project will then show up as child element in Project A and as top level element in the workspace.

Comment: FWIW, I found a really good tutorial on the subject: http://pymatics.com/2011/12/23/tutorial-develop-a-private-framework-for-your-mac-app-using-xcode-4s-workspace-feature I am doing the same thing, but having a little trouble with the application finding the headers.

Answer (score -3):

Good article about project dependencies in Xcode 4: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=14XR5zcZb2Kz2s6A4AbzB00NLkrW9bWxMMprVsUao-hY